# Nash Embedding Theorems for Pseudo-Riemannian Manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Are there analogs of the Nash Embedding Theorems for Pseudo-Riemannian Manifolds?

Comment: Yes, and the proof much easier, one can explicitly can write a formula for the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{N,N}$

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Why not give a reference? Others might stumble upon this question through a web search and find your reference useful.

Comment: @AlexM. There is an explicit construction is called Nash twist. For the given metric $g$ it produce one parameter family of embeddings $f_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with induced metric $g+t{\cdot}h$ for some fixed metric $h$. The embedding $x\mapsto (2{\cdot}f_t(x), f_{2\cdot t}(x))$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N,N}$ is isometric. I learned it from Gromov's book on partial differential relations.

Answer (score 12):

See here:

MR0262980  Reviewed Greene, Robert E. Isometric embeddings of Riemannian and pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society, No. 97 American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I. 1970 iii+63 pp. (Reviewer: W. F. Pohl)

Answer (score 5):

Not clear where you are headed with your concise question, 
but if you have any interest in Lorenzian manifolds as instances of pseudo-Riemannian manifolds,
then this might be of interest, especially for the theorem of Campbell:

"The embedding of General Relativity in five dimensions."
Carlos Romero, Reza Tavakol, Roustam Zalaletdinov.
*General Relativity and Gravitation*.
March 1996, Volume 28, Issue 3, pp 365-376. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02106973).)

> **Abstract**.
>   We argue that General Relativistic solutions can always be locally embedded in Ricci-flat 5-dimensional spaces. This is a direct consequence of a theorem of Campbell (given here for both a timelike and spacelike extra dimension, together with a special case of this theorem) which guarantees that any $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold can be locally embedded in an $(n+1)$-dimensional Ricci-flat Riemannian manifold. [...]

And there are many papers in some sense following, e.g.: "The embedding of space–times in five dimensions with nondegenerate Ricci tensor,"
F. Dahia and C. Romero, *J. Math. Phys.* 43, 3097 (2002). ([AIP link](http://jmp.aip.org/resource/1/jmapaq/v43/i6/p3097_s1?isAuthorized=no).)

Comment: I see the "locally embedded" part, but surely an $S^{3}XS^{1}$ spacetime topology needs an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{4,2}$ to yield a global vector basis (in order to describe the parallelization thereof)