# coordinate free foundations of trigonometry

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, foundations, trigonometric-sums

What axioms for geometry and trigonometry would I have to chose in order to completely avoid coordinates in defining trig functions and showing the equivalence of their geometric (unit circle) and series realizations.

This is usually done by calculating arclengt in a coordinate system but I want to avoid completely any explicit or implicit use of coordinates.

Since a circle is a set of all points equidistant from a given point, it follows that it is a limit of a sequence of regular n sided polygons as n goes to infinity

How do I show that a half lenght side of one n sided poligon is the sine function of   pi over n? Without in any way introducing coordinates

What way would there even be to define or calculate pi in such an axiomatic coordinate less setting

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_geometry ; isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking something akin to a synthetic approach, but augmented with formulas that can be used without adopting coordinate systems

Comment: I am not really sure why this question has been closed. It might have been more clearly formulated but it is still interesting and -imo- there are still more and interesting things to be said. Alexandre Eremenko's answer is certainly valuable but i think there are various ways to define trigonometric functions in "axiomatic" or "coordinate-free" ways,  coming from different areas (from rep theory to differential equations and from complex analysis to the study of functional equations).

Comment: So i have voted to reopen.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou I did not vote to close, but I found the wording of the question unclear, and I couldn't get a good idea of what would satisfy the OP as being "co-ordinate free" -- see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352362/what-is-a-coordinate-less-definition-of-differentiable-manifolds and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3484627/formal-definition-of-position-vectors for context

Comment: It doest matter what I consider coordinate free(thaugh I explained it clearly in all my posts those lines if for some reason that is of interest here..  I staded it perfectly unambiguously here too look at the description:"without in any way introducing coordinates",...

Comment: There are nice characterizations/definitions of the trig functions in terms of functional relations; these do not make any direct reference to any kind of coordinates. I believe the most well known is the following one: Let $p$ be a real number and $C(x)$, $S(x)$ be real valued functions of a real variable satisfying the following conditions: (a). $C(x-y)=C(x)C(y)+S(x)S(y)$ for all real $x,y$, (b). $S(p)=1$ and (c). $S(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,p]$. Then $S$ and $C$ are uniquely determined.

Comment: This result is shown in detai in: G. B. Robison, "A New Approach to Circular Functions, π and lim(sinx)/x", Math. Mag. 41 (1968), 66–70.

Comment: Actually the author lays the foundations carefully: in the same paper, it is shown that $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ defined by the three conditions above are continuous functions.Then, he defines $\pi$ as follows: Taking the (unique) solutions $S(x)$, $C(x)$ resulting from the above conditions for $p=1$, he shows that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{S(x)}{x}$ exists (for $p=1$) he proposes the definition: $\pi = 2\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{S(x)}{x}$.

Comment: Then, the usual sine function is defined through: $\sin(x) = S(\frac{2x}{\pi})$ and the same for the cosine. (this is equivalent to saying that the usual sin, cos are the unique solutions of the above functional condition for $p=\frac{\pi}{2}$ but the way the author works through this, enables him to define $\pi$ from skratch).

Comment: Furthermore, the above presentation provides an easy way of identifying the above definition of the trig functions with the power series definitions: Starting from the series defs we can show that conditions (a), (b), (c), laid above, are satisfied. (This is a little technical, it uses the binomial theorem and the Cauchy product; see for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/626793/195021).

Comment: Thus, (due to the uniqueness of the $S$, $C$ functions, shown in the paper, for any particular value of $p$) it is directly shown that the series definitions are the same with the sine and the cosine functions defined through the functional relation.

Comment: And since the high school functions can be shown (through geometric arguments) that they also satisfy the preceding conditions these are also identified with the functional and the series definitions.

Comment: It is interesting to mention, that the method described in the preceding comments is far from being the only one: A variant of the above method (based on functional eqs and taking continuity as an assumption beforehand) can be found at Proposition 1 of the following answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/834572/195021. (a proof is included by the author, following Robison's paper).

Comment: I have added two more tags, which i think are relevant.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou I don't think those tags are relevant; the OP is not asking about how to teach these concepts. FWIW I was taught as an undergraduate an approach that I believe is quite standard, defining the power series of exp, defining cos and sin in terms of exp, showing that cos has at least one positive real root and defining pi/2 to be the smallest such, deriving the familiar addition formulas and calculus formulas for cos and sin, etc etc

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou Then if one wishes to show that these functions model certain aspects of Euclidean geometry I guess you posit a 2-dimensional real inner product space (abstractly), you set up some axioms for what you believe an "angle" is, and then you show that the functions defined as in my previous concept do indeed have the desired properties when you use the chosen definition of "angle". But this all seems to be what Alexandre Eremenko has already pointed out in his answer.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou BTW, if the OP is somehow hoping to avoid a choice of orthonormal basis (a.k.a fixing x-axis and y-axis) then I suspect at some point one will have to say "let u and v be orthonormal vectors" since otherwise we have problems even talking about right-angled triangles, but of course there is no need to fix a particular isomorphism of our Euclidean space E with R^2 at the start, if that is what the OP is seeking to avoid

Comment: Yea I wish to avoid adopting a basis or anything like that.

Comment: this is exactly what the question is about, new approach to circ functions and pi and lim nsin(x/n). As long as it's not usi g coordinates or ortho normal basis

Comment: What do you mean I'm not asking about how to tech these concepts?

Answer (score 7):

Trigonometric functions do not belong to geometry. Neither does the "measurement of angles" by real numbers.
They belong to analysis. This fact is discussed in detail in the book of Dieudonne, Linear algebra and geometry, Houghton Mifflin Co., Boston, Mass. 1969. (French original: Algèbre linéaire et géométrie élémentaire. (French) Enseignement des Sciences, VIII Hermann, Paris 1964.)

Shortly, the situation is the following: in geometry the group $SO(2)$ is defined.
Then, when the ground field is $R$, there is a continuous homomorphism $R\to SO(2)$,
which is called the exponential. Then trigonometric functions are defined as matrix elements of this homomorphism. Existence of this homomorpsism is proved
using Calculus. When normalized so that derivative at $0$ equals $1$, the positive generator of the kernel is called $2\pi$.
Then one obtains power series etc. An especially elegant exposition is obtained when one uses complex numbers. See Whittaker Watson, vol. I,
Appendix, or Ahlfors, Complex Analysis, or Bourbaki, Topology.

*Remark* Interestingly, the ancient Greeks apparently understood this somehow. For them trigonometry and angle measurement were not parts of pure Geometry. Greek mathematicians never used them in their pure geometric investigations. For Euclid and his followers, the existence of an angle
of $2\pi/7$ radian is dubious, since he cannot construct it. 
Trigonometry and angle measurement were parts of applied mathematics (astronomy, geography, geodesy). In medieval times this distinction was blurred, and it is still blurred in education.

Comment: Norman Wildberger has shown that trigonometry can be developed without using analysis, albeit by avoiding the notion of an angle

Comment: I agree that distinction is blurry, but does that mean that in the theory of pure geometry the ratio of circle length and radius is an undecidable question?

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko  Also there are ways to have a rotation group representation without matrices or hyper complex numbers. Every rotation is a composition of two reflections, and in some systems, variations of Clifford algebra where this ratation groups are equivalent to spinors in a completely coordinate free way.

Comment: @ogogmad What Wildberger has and hasn't "shown" seems rather debatable, once one strips away all the ultrafinitist polemic

Comment: @Ezio How do you propose to define the "length" of a circle? There is a reason why Archimedes used the principle of exhaustion

Comment: @Ezio I fail to see what Clifford algebras have to do with the question you actually asked. It is true that you can define rotations and reflections without coordinates, Alexandre himself says that the group SO(2) comes from geometry. However, to do actual measurements you need a frame of reference, which seems to be the "coordinates" that you are so keen to avoid

Comment: In the answer it's stated that trig functions are defined as matrices of the homomorphism. So instead of matrix algebras you use Clifford algebras, certain spinors as their elements..

Comment: @Yemon Choi we are some thousands of years past archimedes, regardless, evidently now, one has to define angle either using arclengt or arch area of a circle,  I just want to show that both are proportional to pi as given by some infinite series one calculates it with